# How to resolve to a StaticResourceExtension's Property Member

Tags: c#, xaml

Okay here's the scenario.

I've got a type, "ContainerHost" with two properties "PresentationLayerContainer" and "CrosscuttingConcernsContainer" which are both Unity Containers (but that's really not important to our situation.)

I want to be able to define a Static Resource of type "ContainerHost" and then access the properties directly as part of the {StaticResource} markup extension.  Something like this

```
<SomeObject>
   <SomeObject.SomeDependencyProperty SomeContainer="{StaticResource ContainerHost.PresentationLayerContainer}"/>
<SomeObject>
```

Comment: The syntax that doesn't exist? I think you are thinking binding sir.

Comment: Except bindings require Dependency Objects... which I was trying to avoid.

Comment: "which I was trying to avoid" - Yes, I totally misread your question. And that while you were so explicit about it. Sorry.

Comment: It can be said that by specifying a constraint of "StaticResourceExtension" I'm intentionally avoiding binding...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if you want to have your Properties static or not.
c#-part

```
public class ContainerHost{
  public static object StaticPresentationLayerContainer { get; set; }
  public object PresentationLayerContainer { get; set; }
}
```

Xaml

```
<Window ...
  xmlns:proj="clr-namespace:YourProject" >

<!-- for instance-based access -->
<Window.Resources>
  <proj:ContainerHost x:Key="containerHost1" />
</Window.Resources>
<SomeObject>
  <SomeObject.SomeDependencyProperty SomeContainer="{StaticResource containerHost1.PresentationLayerContainer}"/>
<SomeObject>

<!-- For static access -->
<SomeObject>
  <SomeObject.SomeDependencyProperty SomeContainer="{x:Static Member=proj:ContainerHost.StaticPresentationLayerContainer}"/>
<SomeObject>
```